# Guardar datos de un json para despues arma mi pantalla de inicio

Tags: json, flutter, http

Hola estoy aprendiendo flutter, necesito realizar lo siguiente, utilizo http para traer los siguientes datos,necesito sacar por ejemplo el año y la cedula para guardarlos en una variable para despues armar una pantalla y mostrar esos datos,

```
Map data = {
  'id_company': '000000',
  "idc": "00000000"
};
final body = json.encode(data);
// peticion = await http.post(Uri.parse('http://xxxxxxx/get_data_contract'), headers: {"Content-Type": "application/json"}, body: body);
final response = await _httpClient.post((uri),body: body);
return builder(json.decode(response.body)['messaje'][0]);
 }
```

con este codigo traigo los datos de internet, he utilizado un FutureBuilder pero no me permite solo guardar. mi requerimiento es solo guardar ciertos datos para despues presentarlos.
EL idc se debe pasar como una variable

```
{
"errors": [],
"messaje": [
{
"anio": "2021",
"cedula": "09999999",
"codigo_unico": "02000092328261001",
"dia": "16",
"emitido": "2021-07-01",
       
        
}]
}
```

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Has hecho dos veces la misma pregunta... Sibla respuesta no te valía, podrías haber editado la anterior. Deberías proveer un ejemplo de lo que has intentado. También, debes tener en cuenta que no podemos adivinar qué quieres hacer. Debería intentar, en la medida de lo posible, redactar de manera sencilla y comprensible cual es el problema/duda qué quieres solventar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pese a la ambigüedad de la pregunta, para guardar los datos de una peticion http tienes varias opciones, la forma que te recomiendo es usando Bloc pattern
https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_bloc

La otras formas seria guardar la información en shared preferences, streams o servicios.
https://medium.com/comunidad-flutter/usando-streams-en-flutter-28c9357772a9
https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences

Con todas ellas puedes guardar la info y recuperarla despues para mostrarla en una pantalla.